# useForm and react-hook-form is giving problems with I use it with NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-form

I'm coding in NextJs and I needed to use 'useForm' but it keeps giving constant errors... "Cannot resolve 'react-hook-form'."Please help.

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Presignup() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm;
  const submitHandler = (i) => {
    {
      console.log(i);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm facing it as well now

Answer (score 5):

maybe am late to answer this
get the version of *react-hook-form* you installed using

> `npm install react-hook-form`

in my case it is version 7.34.2

in your *project's root directory*... open **package.json** and into the *dependencies object*, add

> **`"react-hook-form": "7.34.2"`**

then run `npm install` in teminal on your *project's root directory*

this worked for me

Comment: Note: As of `npm 5.0.0`, there's is no need to manually save the module dependency in `package.json`. This is done automatically by `npm`, by default. Prior to that, we would use the `--save` option.

Answer (score 1):

this should be quite simple, try this solution:

1. Try to go to `package.json`, see if you already have `react-hook-form` library in it.

##### if you do have it:

2. run `yarn` or `npm install` on your directory terminal

##### if you don't have it:

2. run `yarn add react-hook-form` or `npm install react-hook-form`

Comment: I've already tried that. I'm still receiving the same error

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem, and i found the solution, try this:**

1. Uninstall the `node_modules`
2. After uninstall, paste `npm i` in your terminal
3. Enjoy :)

> If the same problem continues after following my steps, try
> reinstalling Node.js

Answer (score 0):

To use React Hook form in next js, you need to create a component and import that component in you page.jsx. In my case I'm using next.js app route and for a signup functionality I've created a component name as Login.jsx(you can name whatever you want) and import that in your login route, for Example import the login.jsx in Login/page.jsx.

Important Note: define the component and page as 'user client' at the top of the file. In mycase I've used 'user client' in my Login.jsx component and Login/page.jsx file.